# ZREMRANGEBYSCORE does not have count as parameter and instead it removes all elements from Sorted Set between min & max

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm using Sorted Set for storing Agent details which are sorted based on the number of chats they have currently. So number of chats is being used as the score for sorting.

I want to remove & get the least busy Agent from the Sorted Set within a max threshold(5) score.

Eg: Let's say we have 2 agents. agent1 has 5 as score(number of chats), whereas agent2 has 10 as score(number of chats).

```
redisClient.zadd('sorted_agents', 5, 'agent1')
redisClient.zadd('sorted_agents', 10, 'agent2')
```

Now my threshold chat for an agent is 5 and as both agents have 5 or more chats, so my output should be null. If any agent has a score(number of chats) less than the threshold score(5) then that should be removed & returned.

**Approach 1: ZPOPMIN**

```
redisClient.ZPOPMIN(key)
```

Zpopmin doesn't support min and max score values, it will remove agent1 as it has a minimum score amongst 2 agents but agent1 has reached threshold score(5), so I have to manually put a check for this threshold in the code and if it is greater than the threshold I have to put it back in sorted_agents set and return null
**Disadvantage:** I want to remove this additional check in code and let Redis handle it via some min & max parameters

**Approach 2: ZREMRANGEBYSCORE**

```
redisClient.ZREMRANGEBYSCORE(key, min, max)
```

ZREMRANGEBYSCORE doesn't support count though it supports min & max. Since it does not support count it removes all the agents from sorted_agent within min & max score set which is not my requirement.
**Disadvantage:** I do not want to remove all agents instead 1 agent between min & max at a time.

**Approach 3: MULTI command with ZRANGEBYSCORE + ZREM**

```
redisClient.MULTI()
.ZRANGEBYSCORE(key, min, max, 'LIMIT', offset, count)
.ZREM(key, value)
.EXEC()
```

ZRANGEBYSCORE supports min & max score, limit & offset but it does not remove element, it just returns the element so I have to use it with ZREM command. In order to do this in 1 transaction I have to use MULTI command but in MULTI command we cannot get a value & then manipulate/remove the value.
**Disadvantage:** Since I'm using 2 commands so I want 1 atomic transaction but Multi command does not support getting a value and manipulating/removing the same value in 1 transaction.

**Can anyone suggest a better approach for this?**

Comment: Have you considered a [Lua script](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/eval-intro/)?

Comment: I read other answers and they have mentioned Lua Script but I'm trying to understand if is there any other way apart from Lua Script.